# Convert string in xml document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I am getting some xml in a string variable through a wcf webservice. I need to confirm that the string xml I am getting is a valid xml or not.

and I would also like to convert this string to xml document for further processing.
Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`XDocument.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx)

```
string str =
@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<!-- comment at the root level -->
<Root>
    <Child>Content</Child>
</Root>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

Or if you want to catch the parsing error, use [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387040.aspx):

```
try {
    XElement contacts = XElement.Parse(
        @"<Contacts>
            <Contact>
                <Name>Jim Wilson</Name>
            </Contact>
          </Contcts>");

    Console.WriteLine(contacts);
}
catch (System.Xml.XmlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use XElement.Parse : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse.aspx

Comment: In order to avoid the exceptions thrown by Parse at least some of the time, you can do a very crude check to ensure the string starts with `<` and ends with `>`. Trying to do anything more would likely be more expensive than the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can validate the wcf response xml with MessageInspector.MSDN contains a worked example of how this can be accomplished using WCF MessageInspectors

Comment: Thanks, can you pass me the link.

Comment: there is already a thread in stack overflow talking about this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178656/validating-wcf-web-service-xml-body-using-a-messageinspector